# javascript | json parse

Tags: javascript, css, json, filereader

I'm using filereader API:

```
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {

} else {

    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
    return;
}   

input = document.id('fileinput');

if (!input) {
    alert("Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
} else if (!input.files) {
    alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
} else if (!input.files[0]) {
    alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");               
} else {
    file    = input.files[0];
    fr      = new FileReader();     
    fr.onload = function () {
        console.log(JSON.parse(fr.result));
    }

    fr.readAsText(file); 
}
```

I'm getting this in my console:

```
{"id":"2","name":"Links1","position":"1","author":"Demo","email":"info@demo.com","description":"","html":"<div class=\"units-row-end\" id=\"links\"><\/div>","css":"","js":"var out = '<a href=\"#!index\" class=\"home\">Home<\/a> ';\nout += user.type ? '<a href=\"#!logout\">Logout<\/a> ' : '<a href=\"#!login\">Login<\/a> ';\nout += user.type ==2 ? '<a href=\"#!admin?template=overview\">Account<\/a> ' : user.type == 1 ? '<a href=\"#!user?template=overview\">Account<\/a> ' : '';\nout += user.type !=2 ? '<a href=\"#!cart\">Cart<\/a>' : '';\n\ndocument.id('links').set('html', out);","status":"1"}
```

This output is not an object in my console! Why?
If I'm trying to copy the string above and past into: http://json.parser.online.fr/ this string converts into object.
Where is a problem?

P.S
My file contents (fr.result):

```
"{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Links1\",\"position\":\"1\",\"author\":\"Demo\",\"email\":\"info@demo.com\",\"description\":\"\",\"html\":\"<div class=\\\"units-row-end\\\" id=\\\"links\\\"><\\\/div>\",\"css\":\"\",\"js\":\"var out = '<a href=\\\"#!index\\\" class=\\\"home\\\">Home<\\\/a> ';\\nout += user.type ? '<a href=\\\"#!logout\\\">Logout<\\\/a> ' : '<a href=\\\"#!login\\\">Login<\\\/a> ';\\nout += user.type ==2 ? '<a href=\\\"#!admin?template=overview\\\">Account<\\\/a> ' : user.type == 1 ? '<a href=\\\"#!useraccount?template=overview\\\">Account<\\\/a> ' : '';\\nout += user.type !=2 ? '<a href=\\\"#!cart\\\">Cart<\\\/a>' : '';\\n\\ndocument.id('links').set('html', out);\",\"status\":\"1\"}"
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(fr.result)` is an object. Check it- `console.log(typeof JSON.parse(fr.result))`

Comment: Console show me: string

Comment: We'd need to know what `fr.result` looks like and what console we're talking about (Firefox? Firebug? Chrome? Internet Explorer?). The rest of the code about FileReader API does not seem as relevant.

Comment: Please check my fs.result (file contents) above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your actual file contents (as shown when opening the file with a text editor rather than dumping `fr.result` with the Firefox console) are exactly this:

```
"{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Links1\",\"position\":\"1\",\"author\":\"Demo\",\"email\":\"info@demo.com\",\"description\":\"\",\"html\":\"<div class=\\\"units-row-end\\\" id=\\\"links\\\"><\\\/div>\",\"css\":\"\",\"js\":\"var out = '<a href=\\\"#!index\\\" class=\\\"home\\\">Home<\\\/a> ';\\nout += user.type ? '<a href=\\\"#!logout\\\">Logout<\\\/a> ' : '<a href=\\\"#!login\\\">Login<\\\/a> ';\\nout += user.type ==2 ? '<a href=\\\"#!admin?template=overview\\\">Account<\\\/a> ' : user.type == 1 ? '<a href=\\\"#!useraccount?template=overview\\\">Account<\\\/a> ' : '';\\nout += user.type !=2 ? '<a href=\\\"#!cart\\\">Cart<\\\/a>' : '';\\n\\ndocument.id('links').set('html', out);\",\"status\":\"1\"}"
```

... that explains the issue.

First of all, you don't really have valid JSON, as any [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com) will reveal. In the JSON data format, the top level element must be an object or an array, and yours is a string. However, the [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method apparently allows these cases of JSON subelements (probably because being able to decode them is a useful and easy to implement feature).

But since you have nothing but a single string, that's what you get after decoding it: a string. As far as JSON is concerned, your data format is not different from this:

```
"Hello, World!"
```

I suspect the problem is in the code you use to *generate* the JSON file. It looks like it's **encoding the output twice**. It should probably look like this:

```
{"id":"2","name":"Links1","position":"1","author":"Demo","email":"info@demo.com","description":"","html":"<div class=\"units-row-end\" id=\"links\"><\/div>","css":"","js":"var out = '<a href=\"#!index\" class=\"home\">Home<\/a> ';\nout += user.type ? '<a href=\"#!logout\">Logout<\/a> ' : '<a href=\"#!login\">Login<\/a> ';\nout += user.type ==2 ? '<a href=\"#!admin?template=overview\">Account<\/a> ' : user.type == 1 ? '<a href=\"#!useraccount?template=overview\">Account<\/a> ' : '';\nout += user.type !=2 ? '<a href=\"#!cart\">Cart<\/a>' : '';\n\ndocument.id('links').set('html', out);","status":"1"}
```

Please note that the leading and trailing quotes are gone (together with all the backslash escape sequences inside). This way, you have an encoded object and you get a decoded object.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. To rewrite you file (like an obvious js file):
   {"id":"2","name":"Links1","position":"1", ...
2. If you can't change your file use this trick:

   fr.onload = function () {

   eval('var temp = ' + fr.result + ';');

   console.log(JSON.parse(temp));

   }

Comment: Please check it after P.S

Comment: Yes. And what? How can I convert this into object?

Comment: I'm tried to use eval still nothing. String as output.